# Magento Secure Magmi from unauthorized access using htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi, htaccess, .htaccess

I'm using below htaccess file to prevent unauthorized access to Magmi.

> /{root_path}/{magmi_dir}/.htaccess

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 202.131.115.180 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

this htaccess file is working fine when I'm trying to access Magmi from a browser but **it's preventing me to access Magmi when I'm trying to call magmi script from observer using curl**.

I've added `127.0.0.1` and `server IP` in htaccess to whitelist server itself but it's still not allowing me to access Magmi from the observer.

How can I whitelist server itself so that I can call Magmi script from Magento observer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

make a curl to http://canihazip.com/s to find out the IP of the webserver  when making remote requests. It could be this differs from the incomming server IP.

Add that IP to your whitelist.

Alernatify, you can dump the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` with a `die();` in the `index.php` and remove the `.htaccess` block. Make a curl, see what the IP is, add that to the `.htaccess` whitelist.